# Twitter Widget Not Working on Mobile

Tags: twitter

I have a few sites that display twitter feeds using the blogger.js & twitterCallback2 scripts.

The twitter feed shows up great on desktop versions of the site, but on mobile it does not load. I get an error message...

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) | mobile.twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"

So it looks like it tries to load a mobile version of the script, but the script is not there.

Anyone else have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this problem on some of our Wordpress websites.
The link `mobile.twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js` should just be `twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js`

Since twitter has a mobile redirect, it wouldn't allow us to use this link for mobile. So we made our own blogger.js

Here's a link on how we resolved it. Hope this helps:
http://www.clarkcommunications.ca/twitter-widget-not-working-on-mobile/